# Frame without one of the borders

Tags: framed, border

I'm trying to replicate the equation shown below. I can't figure out how to put parts of it in a frame without one of the borders.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go with a normal tabular with one open column. Defining a new command can be quite handy for this. Here is one implementation of it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ltab}[1]{\begin{tabular}{|@{}l@{}}
\hline
\ensuremath{#1}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\rtab}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}|}
\hline
\ensuremath{#1}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\[
\ltab{\hat{g}} = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi\delta}{\sigma_1((X+Y)(X-Y))^{\sigma_2}}} 
\;\rtab{\approx 999.121}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly and commands proved to be useful in later equations, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution with a `tcbox` from `tcolorbox` which offers all its bells and whistles.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{%
    nobeforeafter,
    math upper,
    tcbox raise base,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=1pt,
    right=1pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    boxrule=1pt
    }

\newtcbox{\lbox}[1][]{
    rightrule=0pt, #1}

\newtcbox{\rbox}[1][]{
    leftrule=0pt, #1}

\begin{document}

\[
    \lbox[colback=green!30]{\hat{g}} = 
    \sqrt{\frac{4\pi\delta}{\sigma_1((X+Y)(X-Y))^{\sigma_2}}} 
    \;\rbox[colframe=red]{\approx 999.121}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]